# AJAX only works with jQuery version 1.7.0?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a menu show/hide, but it only works with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My website uses a local version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".m-menu").click(function(){
        $(".m-menu").toggleClass("active");
        $(".mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
        $(".mobile-menu-bg").addClass("active");
    });

    $(".mobile-menu").css('left','-200px');
    $(".mobile-menu-bg").css('left','-200px');
    $(".m-menu").toggle(function() {
        $('.mobile-menu').animate({ left: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('.mobile-menu-bg').animate({ left: '0' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
    }, 
    function() {       
        $('.mobile-menu-bg').animate({ left: '-200' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $('.mobile-menu').animate({ left: '-200' }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
    }
    );
});
```

What is the problem here? should I use jQuery 1.7.0 because of this menu? Why it is not working on 1.11.2?

Comment: Do you see some kind of error in your console?

Comment: What is your ajax code? If you hit f12 or go to tools->Developer tools do you see any errors? What "doesn't work"? If you look at the network tab do you see it attempt to perform the call?

Comment: .toggle is not working on version 1.11.2 properly, so menu not show/hide.